# Maven is pulling an older version of HTMLUnit even though I specified the newest (?)

Tags: java, maven, htmlunit

I added htmlunit to my POM file using the website's suggested

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
  <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

But I'm trying to create a webclient, like this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
```

But it gives me this error:

```
BEST_SUPPORTED cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

So I just looked at the options, and it gives me these:
[image]

Which seem like they are coming from a much older version of HTMLUnit, because according tot he [javadocs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html) they have Firefox 45 and Microsoft Edge, etc... which I don't have as an option.

How do I get Maven in Eclipse to use the newer version of HTMLunit?

I've tried mvn install
mvn clean > mvn install

Right click the project in Eclipse > Maven > Update project.

This is from mvn dependency:tree

```
     --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ vaadin-app ---
[INFO] org.test:vaadin-app:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.vaadin.external.streamhtmlparser:streamhtmlparser-jsilver:jar:0.0.10.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:jar:1.3.0.gg2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:7.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:guava:jar:16.0.1.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-push:jar:7.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.vaadin.external.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:jar:2.2.7.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.vaadin.external.slf4j:vaadin-slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:7.6.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:jar:7.6.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.6.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.transaction:jar:1.1.1.v201105210645:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.mail.glassfish:jar:1.4.1.v201005082020:provided
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.activation:jar:1.1.0.v201105071233:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.annotation:jar:1.1.0.v201108011116:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:org.objectweb.asm:jar:3.1.0.v200803061910:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jdesktop:swing-worker:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.19:provided
[INFO] |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:50.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler-deps:jar:1.2.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:7.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ucanaccess:ucanaccess:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.healthmarketscience.jackcess:jackcess:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.17.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.17.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.17.v20160517:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.17.v20160517:compile
[INFO] \- org.vaadin:viritin:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO]    +- org.vaadin.addon:confirmdialog:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.commonjava.googlecode.markdown4j:markdown4j:jar:2.2-cj-1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
```

Comment: Resorting to command line should help you unravel something. Do `mvn dependency:tree` (using the so-called dependency plugin) should tell you exactly how your dependencies are set up.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade I added the dependency tree as an edit. It looks like my I have two versions of nekohtml, one is 1.9 and another is 2.21, but I looked in my pom file and the 1.9 version isn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete your local repo directory for htmlunit and then try update project.

Comment: I actually couldn't find the HTMLUnit folder in my repository, but I deleted some stuff in the same folder it would have been in (projectfolder/org/apache/ and just deleted http related stuff) and redid my POM file, removing htmlunit, then updated +installed, then added the dependency back to the POM and updated / installed and that seemed to have worked.